# Hibernate Auxiliary Database Objects - Trigger not being created

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, triggers

I'm trying to setup a Postgres trigger in my Hibernate mapping file, but it doesn't seem to create the trigger in the database. I can create the trigger manually in Postgres, but prefer to let Hibernate do all schema/DDL creation I have hbm2dll.auto=update in my hibernate.cfg.xml and my mapping is:

```
     <hibernate-mapping>
    <class>
(class def here)
    </class>    
    <database-object>
        <create>CREATE TRIGGER genUuid BEFORE INSERT ON metar FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE uuid_gen();</create>
            <drop></drop>
                <dialect-scope name="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
    </database-object>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

But no trigger is created for table "metar". What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this my setting the hbm2ddl.auto to "create" in my hibernate.cfg.xml. It seems that "update" causes it to ignore the  tags all together.